# ¿Cómo puedo poner un texto justificado en R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Intenté con el código

```
<div style="text-align: justify"> 
<div/>
```

encerrando mi texto, pero no funciónó. Dejo una imagen mostrando exactamente cómo lo escribí

[image]

Comment: También probé el siguiente código  y no funcionó
<div class=text-justify>

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta rápida: **No se puede**

`Markdown` es un lenguaje que está pensado para ser independiente del medio en que se lo representa y la alineación de un texto requiere que exista previamente una página con cierto tamaño, un concepto que markdown no maneja.

De todas formas hay algunas alternativas para superar esta limitación, pero todas son dependientes del medio en el cual se representa el código, una solución para la salida `html` solo funciona para este medio, igual para `pdf` o `word`

##### 1. `html`

```
## Esto solo funciona para HTML

### Alineación Centrada:
<div align="center"> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
</div>

### Alineación a Izquierda:
<div align="left">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
</div>

### Alineación a derecha:
<div align="right">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
</div>

### Justificado:
<div align="justify">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
</div>
```

##### 2. `pdf`

```
## Esto solo funciona en PDF

### Alineación Centrada:
\begin{center}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
\end{center}

### Alineación a Izquierda:
\begin{flushleft}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
\end{flushleft}

### Alineación a derecha:
\begin{flushright}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
\end{flushright}

### Justificado (En latex/pdf el default es justificado):
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in pellentesque est. Maecenas non velit id felis auctor facilisis. Mauris enim enim, placerat ut lobortis id, euismod eu risus. Cras ligula massa, aliquam at orci vel, suscipit pulvinar massa. Nam tempor congue felis, vel hendrerit ex viverra sit amet. Sed dictum sagittis lacus non gravida. Nunc in nulla varius, volutpat quam et, cursus nulla. Nam et elit nec dui lobortis lacinia.
```

##### 3. `word`

Acá el tema es más limitado aún, ya que no puedes establecer una alineación particular para un párrafo dentro del código `markdown`, solo puedes modificar los estilos de manera general, por ejemplo los distintos encabezados o en tu caso podría ser el estilo "Normal". Para esto, hay que armar un documento secundario con la configuración de los estilos. Lo que podrías hacer, es generar tu documento y renombrarlo como `estilos.docx`, lo editas y tienes que modificar el formato del estilo del texto (no el texto), para esto tomas un párrafo que corresponda al estilo "Normal", lo justificas y luego sobre este texto, botón derecho, vas a "estilos" y sobre el estilo "Normal" nuevamente botón derecho y "Actualizar normal para que coincida con la selección". Finalmente salvas el documento y en la cabecera de tu documento `r-markdown` agregas este template de estilos:

```
output:
  word_document: 
    reference_docx: estilos.docx
```

En este caso `pandoc` que es la herramienta que usa `R` para generar el output, tomara `estilos.docx` como modelo para definir los estilos finales de tu documento.

De toda formas, te sugiero que leas [Happy collaboration with Rmd to docx](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) que explica esto con mayor profundidad.